# AWS CloudFormation - Attach existing managed policy to existing role through a template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am deploying a CloudFormation template to AWS. A role for my Lambda invocation is being created by a template that I am importing, and I cannot modify it directly. I wish to modify that role to attach the AWS managed policy `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` that already exists in my AWS account. So far, all of my searches have come up empty.

1. I have found instructions for how to create a new role with an existing managed policy
2. I have found instructions for how to create a new policy and attach it to an existing role.
3. I have found instructions for how to Update a Stack using the AWS console or the CLI, but not via a template (YAML or JSON)
4. I have found instructions for calling something called `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` in something called Terraform, but that is not available to me

I am hoping for something like the following but I cannot find any evidence of this existing anywhere. Is there anything that can do what I am trying to do?

```
---
Resources:
  AdditionalRolePermissions:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::RolePolicyAttachment"
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - Ref: ExistingRole
      PolicyName:
        - Ref: ExistingPolicy
```

The best solution I have come up with so far is to create a new policy that has a manually created PolicyDocument that is the same as the existing one for `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole`  and attach it to the role upon creation. I would prefer not to do that though because it will be harder to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not do this in pure CloudFormation unless you create a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) but this isn't really pure CloudFormation at that point as you'd need to create a lambda and other resources to implement the custom resource.  There is no concept of a policy attachment in CloudFormation presently and these attachments only happen when you define a policy or role resource.

The simplest thing would be to go with your solution of creating a policy that duplicates `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole`.  That policy is fairly simple and shouldn't clutter up your CloudFormation template too much compared to some other complicated policies.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible as of 2021. Please see: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-attach-managed-policy/

Example:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: something cool
Resources:
  IAM:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      RoleName: some_role_name
      Policies:
        ['arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole']
```